# Google OAuth2: 'The verifyIdToken method requires an ID Token' error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, token

I have an app where Google OAuth2 used to work fine some time ago, but now it seems that something has changed and it's not working anymore. When I try to login with Google, I get the following message in the response body:

`The verifyIdToken method requires an ID Token`

At first I thought that the problem could be with the implementation of `google-auth-library` on the Node back-end, but, as far as I can tell, it seems that it didn't change, unless I'm missing something.

Here's what I have on the front-end:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import AuthProvider from "./context/AuthContext";
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from "@react-oauth/google";

ReactDOM.render(
  <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}>
  <AuthProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthProvider>
  </GoogleOAuthProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Login.js**

```
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { GoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";
import axios from "../config/axiosConfig";

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { state } = useLocation();
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

function Login() {
  function handleSuccess(response) {
    axios
      .post("/api/auth/google", { token: response.tokenId })
      .then((res) => {
        const { user, isAuthenticated } = res.data;

        authContext.setUser(user);
        authContext.setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);
        navigate(state?.path || "/diary");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  function handleFailure(response) {
    setMessage("Authentication failed");
  }
  
  return (
    <GoogleLogin
      className="google-btn"
      redirectUri={
      isProduction
        ? process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL_PROD
        : process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL_DEV
      }
      onSuccess={handleSuccess}
      onError={handleFailure}
      theme="filled_blue"
      width="312px"
    />
  )
}

export default Login;
```

And, on the server-side, I have this:

**auth.controller.js**

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");
const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);

const google = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { token } = req.body;

    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    });

    const { given_name, family_name, email, sub } = ticket.getPayload();

    User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {
      if (!user) {
        const newUser = new User({
          first_name: given_name,
          last_name: family_name,
          email: email,
          googleId: sub,
        });

        newUser.save();

        generateTokens(newUser, res);

        res.status(201).json({
          isAuthenticated: true,
          user: given_name,
        });
      } else if (user && !user.googleId) {
        user.googleId = sub;
        user.save();

        generateTokens(user, res);

        res.status(200).json({
          isAuthenticated: true,
          user: user.first_name,
        });
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
};
```